# Notebook section inside VSCode settings, What is that?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

As you might notice, one of the features shown under "Features" section is 'Notebook'.

I tried searching with Google, but I only find information about the Jupiter plugin, which is not what I was looking for.

Can anyone explain what VSCode notebooks are and where I can find more information about it? Thanks.

Comment: It's a Jupyter Notebook. Go read about that.

Comment: I think it may be used for VSCode's liveshare feature.